# Show Android SDK Help in Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am used to C# develop  in Microsoft Visual Studio IDE. Now I am trying to develop an Android app.

It is possible in Eclipse to show Android SDK help/information based on the context (e.g. placement of cursor) when I press F1 key like in Visual Studio?

Comment: I think you are looking for `ctrl+spacebar`.

Comment: ctrl+spacebar is to trigger autocompletition. I want the IDE showing the full documentation. For instance, if I am over a "OnItemSelectedListener" it should open something like [SDK doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ctrl+spacebar` will tell you different options you have when you are writing code.
2. When you are having error, just hovering the cursor over the red underlined characters will show you options, or you can place your cursor on words and press `F2` and it will start showing possible options.
3. The icons on left side will tell you about errors or warnings in you code.

Or you can read through [this nice tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseShortcuts/article.html) for more shortcuts.

And also hovering over any method names or anything shows a dialog box, which contains description and links. Clicking on any link will open complete help in eclipse itself.

Comment: Thank you, hovering shows a link. When clicking it the SDK documentation I want is showed. Also, if I press F1 a Help panel shows up with a link to the documentation (for instance: 
Javadoc for 'android.widget.AdapterView.setOnItemSelectedListener(OnItemSelectedListener)')

Answer (score 1):

`For instance, if I am over a "OnItemSelectedListener" it should open something like SDK doc`

Hover on particular code and click on browser icon as shown in below image.

[image]